# Laravel 5.2 How can I display member list with his / her groups in the same row (One to Many ( or Many to Many ) data display)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and learning Laravel 5.2 with MariaDB 10.0.xx.

There are several tables but in brief 'Member' can have many 'Group' and I would like to display Member's First Name and Last Name with the name of groups that member already joined in the same row.

I don't have any clear idea to achieve this but what I am trying to do is to create two separate queries ($memberLists and $groupLists) and get the group list by inputting first query ($memberLists)'s primary key to second query ($groupLists).

or if you have better idea please let me know.

**I want display as below**

```
first Name / Last Name / Groups
john            Doe         A group, B group
Jane            Taylor      B group
Nick            Kay         A group, B group, C group
```

**My controller**

```
$memberLists = DB::table('Member')
                ->select('firstNm','lastNm')
                ->join('Center', 'Member.mbrCd', '=', 'Center.mbrCd')
                ->join('Org', 'Center.orgCd', '=', 'Org.orgCd');

$groupLists = DB::table('Group')
                ->select('groupNm')
                ->join('Center','Center.orgCd','=','Group.orgCd')
                ->join('GroupMember ','GroupMember.mbrCd','=','Center.mbrCd')
                ->where ('GroupMember.mbrCd',$Member_primaryKey_from_memberLists);

view return view('member.memberList')
                ->with('memberLists', $memberLists)
                ->with('groupLists',$groupLists);
```

**This is my view**

```
@extends('masterLayOut')

<table>
<thead>
<th> First Name </th>
<th> Last Name </th>
<th> Groups </th>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach ($memberLists as $memberList)
<tr>
<td> {{ memberList->firstNm}}</td>
<td> {{ memberList->lastNm }}</td>
<td> {{ groupLists->groupNm }} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach

</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is grate example why is good to use the Eloquent models instead of queries. You could resolved this in tho lines with eager loading.

In your example you'll have group everything first of all (I'll omit all the joins besause I don't know if we need it here):

**Controller**

```
//I'm selecting also member id (I don't know how you call it)
$memberLists = DB::table('Member')
    ->select('id', 'firstNm','lastNm')
    ->get();


$groupLists = DB::table('Group')
    ->select('groupNm', 'mbrCd')
    ->get();

$groups = [];

foreach($groupLists as $group) {
    if (!isset($group[$group->mbrCd])) {
        $group[$group->mbrCd] = [];
    }
    $group[$group->mbrCd][] = $group->groupNm;
}

return view('member.memberList')
    ->with('memberLists', $memberLists)
    ->with('groupLists', $groups);
```

Then in your view:

```
@extends('masterLayOut')

<table>
<thead>
<th> First Name </th>
<th> Last Name </th>
<th> Groups </th>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach ($memberLists as $memberList)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ memberList->firstNm}}</td>
        <td> {{ memberList->lastNm }}</td>
        <td> {{ isset($groups[$memberList->id]) ? implode(', ', $groups[$memberList->id]) : '' }} </td>
    </tr>
@foreach

</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: This doesn't look right. You are assuming that `$memberList->id` is also the index of the `$groups` array which it will never be.

Comment: it doesn't looks like one to many relation between Member and Group. it seems that member (with mbrCd) has only single Group. Please let me know your opinion.